# Wordpress autopost

Tags: wordpress

Can i make wordpress autopost the classic "welcome post" lets say once every week. ? Maybe with a cron job? And then, change the post permalink from a few keywords which i select?

TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plugins available.  [Schedule Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/schedule-post/) seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

If that doesn't work, you can programmatically insert and publish posts using

[wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

and

[wp_publish_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_publish_post)

You can get a cron job plugin for WordPress that runs scripts at scheduled intervals / when specific pages are called.  You can use the two wp functions above to create and / or publish a post whenever you want.

Comment: To get access to the whole range of WP functions, you just have to include header.php which is (if I remember right) in the includes folder.